# SuiteCRM Token Expired / Revoked Immediately After creating it

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth, suitecrm

I have installed the SuiteCRM and configured the keys using openssl, then when i try to create any oauth token, its getting created successfully, but its ( oauth token) getting expired and its expiry date-time is 7 hours behind the Date-Created, please check the following screenshot. Please reply as fast as possible.

[image]

So when i use this token in the following get API, i'm getting following error.

**API :**

URL  : http://127.0.0.1:81/suitecrm/api/v8/modules/Accounts

**Header :**

```
Content-type: application/vnd.api+json
 Accept: application/vnd.api+json
 Authorization : Bearer
 eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjQ1YzdiZTExZWQ1ZWQ0OGMwOWVmNWUzYjhk
    YjYyMWI4MTMxNTk4MmE2NzJiNDQ5NzRiZjE0MjFlMjE2OTU3YjJiOTVjZTkwZTMyMjYzYzk3In0.eyJh
    dWQiOiIzYTg2MTUwYS00M2Q5LTMxNDQtNDcwNi01YWZhOGUyMzdlY2QiLCJqdGkiOiI0NWM3YmUxMWVk
    NWVkNDhjMDllZjVlM2I4ZGI2MjFiODEzMTU5ODJhNjcyYjQ0OTc0YmYxNDIxZTIxNjk1N2IyYjk1Y2U5
    MGUzMjI2M2M5NyIsImlhdCI6MTUyNjM2OTk3NywibmJmIjoxNTI2MzY5OTc3LCJleHAiOjE1MjYzNzM1
    NzcsInN1YiI6IiIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJzdGFuZGFyZDpjcmVhdGUiLCJzdGFuZGFyZDpyZWFkIiwic3Rh
    bmRhcmQ6dXBkYXRlIiwic3RhbmRhcmQ6ZGVsZXRlIiwic3RhbmRhcmQ6cmVsYXRpb25zaGlwOmNyZWF0
    ZSIsInN0YW5kYXJkOnJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcDpyZWFkIiwic3RhbmRhcmQ6cmVsYXRpb25zaGlwOnVwZGF0
    ZSIsInN0YW5kYXJkOnJlbGF0aW9uc2hpcDpkZWxldGUiXX0.b8JSGHeseziZsrdXa6TexfmLNkifEmt1
    al-3c0_mnQlJcPUhcoF8K77iRvPBOCc9tYkd19Rq6BlHXxDe1kqCJT9659xfLkTYAziZOI5WeZb8P_D8jPl
    Bq910trERpLNY-12lqnNURiR4K1zAie4064oLBrLmNCvYVI7hvrkkwU4
```

**API RESPONSE WITH ERROR: -**

```
{
"error": "access_denied",
"message": "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.",
"hint": "Access token has been revoked"
}
```

Thanks in Advance, Please help us to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, its a timezone issue, When i change the timezone in the php.ini file to "UTC", everything starts working fine.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is broken in SuiteCRM. See this open GitHub issue.

https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/5711

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In that link, the issue is the oauth toke is not getting generated. But in our case, Oauth token getting created with with expiry time value 7 hours behind the date created value.

Comment: are you on a different version?

Comment: My SuiteCRM version is 7.10.4